# Чи правильно говорити "післявчора"?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, прислівники

Часто, особливо у розмовній мові, зустрічаю вживання слова "післявчора". Це слово використовується тоді, коли мова іде про події, що відбувалися два дні тому.

Гугл, за запитом "післявчора" повертає: `Приблизна кількість результатів: 1 870`

У [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/) такого слова не знайшов. Натомість, є слова "[передучора](http://sum.in.ua/s/pereduchora)" та "[позавчора](http://sum.in.ua/s/pozavchora)".

Підозрюю, що це слово виникло по аналогії до слова "післязавтра".

Отже, чи є допустимим вживання слова "післявчора"? Чи є ще варіанти, окрім "передучора" та "позавчора"?

Comment: `післявчора` - то ж `сьогодні`, ніє?

Comment: На приблизну кількість результатів не можна орієнтуватися. Треба спробувати потрапити на останню сторінку результатів - тоді отримаєте реальну кількість. В мене вийшло "Сторінка 20 з такої кількості результатів: 199 (0,50 сек.)".

Comment: У повсякденному вжитку завжди чув і сам використовував позавчора.

Answer (score 6):

Після - це наступний за чергою, тому казати післявчора доцільно про день сьогоднішній. На одному форумі було [обговорення](http://posydenky.lvivport.com/threads/neznannja-movi-chi-cilkovita-bajduzhist-abo-chomu-govorimo-z-pomilkami.45555/page-45) цієї теми, офіційно якось дуже доцільно вживати, краще реально казати "два дні тому".

А тому, на мою думку, казати "післявчора" неправильно. Просто через те, що ця норма неправомірна для української мови. Так, існує повість з такою назвою, проте це вже авторський неологізм. Так, наприклад, в таблиці неправильних слів та правильних альтернатив це слово зустрічається: [1](http://studopedia.org/7-14608.html), [2](http://uchitel9.webnode.com.ua/kultura-movlennya2/), [3](http://ukrpedpraktira.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_09.html)

Comment: Будь ласка, дайте пряму відповідь на запитання: правильно говорити *післявчора* чи ні, й поясніть чому (з посиланнями на джерела)

Answer (score 3):

На персональному [сайті](https://vikladath.jimdo.com/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E/) вчителя української мови Шкатули Т. М. знайшов інформацію, що казати **"післявчора" неправильно** (а також врахуйте, що цього слова немає в СУМі). Однак, в нашій мові є слово "[позавчора](http://sum.in.ua/s/pozavchora)", а також вислови "напередодні вчорашнього дня" та "два дні тому".

Answer (score 0):

**Український правопис** і **СУМ** регулюють вжиток слів та правила на письмі переважно для офіційно-ділового стилю мовлення. Та вони не обмежують словотвір в художній літературі.

**«Післявчора»** є цілком припустимим, коли це назва твору.

[image]

[Книга «Післявчора», автор Ірина Цілик](https://www.yakaboo.ua/ua/pisljavchora.html)

**"Післявчора"**, на мою думку, тут вживається в сенсі **"після минулих подій"**. Після подій, які назавжди змінили звичайний спосіб життя. Тобто, про сьогодення, до якого тепер потрібно пристосовуватись і про непередбачуване майбутнє.

Comment: Судячи з анотації "післявчора" тут означає "сьогодні".

Comment: − Тут питають не про наявність слова, а радше його смисл. Ну і так, як зазначив Артемікс, анотація книги прямо кажить, що то про «сьоʼдня», а не як сінонім до «позавчора», про що було питаннє.

Comment: @Sútnôstj, автор запитання каже про велику кількість пошукових результатів в Google, проте не наводить жодного прикладу вжитку слова "післявчора" на позначення "позавчора". Моя відповідь пояснює причини наявності цього слова в Гуглі та умови, за яких це слово не є помилкою.